# Python: (DataFrame Plotting) Unable to set year intervals in xticks

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have this data:

```
    Year    GDP        Population
0   1960    540.197     179323175
1   1961    580.612     182992000
2   1962    612.280     185771000
3   1963    653.938     188483000
4   1964    697.319     191141000
50  2010    15240.843   309330219
51  2011    15796.460   311587816
52  2012    16358.863   313873685
53  2013    17083.137   316497531
54  2014    17849.912   318857056
```

I plotted the dataframe but could get only the five years
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkuOZ.png)

I want to show all the years with an interval of 5 years in between and thus used the following code:

```
ax=t[['GDP','Population']].plot();
x=np.arange(0,55,5)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(t['Year']);
```

However, this doesn't work.
My desired output is as below but instead of the number in the xticks, there should be years from 1960-2014 with an interval of 5
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhBhk.png)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
ax=t.plot(x='Year', y=['GDP','Population'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(t['Year'].iloc[0], t['Year'].iloc[-1], step=5),rotation=45) # iloc just gets the element position in pandas series. here first and last.
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: GDP vs. Population Over 5 year interval]